# Rank OVER Window PartitionBy in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I put my hands on a bit of PySpark code that I need to translate in Pandas oriented processing. Any help would be more than welcome since I'm struggling finding my way into Pandas equivalences :

PySpark code:

```py
window = Window.partitionBy(df["timestamp"]).orderBy(df["timestamp"].desc())

df = df.select('*', F.rank().over(window).alias('rank')) \
       .filter(F.col('rank') <= 1) \
       .orderBy(df["timestamp"].desc()) \
       .limit(int(window_int))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sqldf` from `pandasql` to achieve a simple `sql` like window experience. The library actually uses the `sqlite` grammar which supports window functions and each variable/dataframe can be considered a table. The function `sqldf` also returns a `DataFrame`

```py
from pandasql import sqldf

df = sqldf("""
 SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT 
        * ,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp ORDER  BY timestamp ) as rank
     FROM
        df
     ORDER BY timestamp desc
 ) dfsub
 WHERE
    rank <= 1
 LIMIT %d
""" % (int(window_int)))
```